# emacs BibTex mode auto saves a file .el file

Tags: emacs, bibtex

My Emacs 24.3 come with BibTex mode, which is enabled automatically when editing .bib file. I got a strangely problem: whenever i make some modifications to a .bib file, i found a folder named "auto" is generated, and a .el file is saved there in the folder. for instance, when I edit a file called abc.bib, a abs.el file is generated in the folder "auto", which has content as follows:

```
(TeX-add-style-hook "abc"

 (lambda ()

    (LaTeX-add-bibitems)))
```

what is that for? and how can i disable that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it comes from `tex.el`.  I do not think that behavior can be disabled and still maintain the functionality contemplated by AUCTeX.  However, it looks like you could probably modify the path to go into a temporary folder instead -- e.g., `/tmp/auto` -- but you would need to make sure you look at all the functions within AUCTeX that use the variable `TeX-auto-local` and adjust those paths accordingly (if needed).

```
(defcustom TeX-auto-local "auto"
  "*Directory containing automatically generated TeX information.

This correspond to TeX macros found in the current directory, and must
be relative to that."
  :group 'TeX-file
  :type 'string)
```

Here is a quick word-search for that variable:

```
/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/auctex/tex.el:
 1993    :type 'directory)
 1994  
 1995: (defcustom TeX-auto-local "auto"
 1996    "*Directory containing automatically generated TeX information.
 1997  
 ....
 2121  
 2122  (defcustom TeX-auto-private
 2123:   (list (expand-file-name TeX-auto-local
 2124             (or (and (boundp 'user-emacs-directory)
 2125                  (concat user-emacs-directory "auctex/"))
 ....
 2155       (append (list TeX-auto-global TeX-style-global)
 2156           TeX-auto-private TeX-style-private
 2157:          (list TeX-auto-local TeX-style-local)))
 2158      path)
 2159    "List of directories to search for AUCTeX style files.
 2160  Per default the list is built from the values of the variables
 2161  `TeX-auto-global', `TeX-style-global', `TeX-auto-private',
 2162: `TeX-style-private', `TeX-auto-local', and `TeX-style-local'."
 2163    :group 'TeX-file
 2164    :type '(repeat (file :format "%v")))
 ....
 2198                 "./"))
 2199       (TeX-style-path (append (list (expand-file-name
 2200:                         TeX-auto-local dir)
 2201                         (expand-file-name
 2202:                         TeX-auto-local master-dir)
 2203                         (expand-file-name
 2204                          TeX-style-local dir)
 ....
 3167    (if TeX-auto-untabify
 3168        (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
 3169:   (if (and TeX-auto-save TeX-auto-local)
 3170        (let* ((file (expand-file-name
 3171           (concat
 3172:           (file-name-as-directory TeX-auto-local)
 3173            (TeX-strip-extension nil TeX-all-extensions t)
 3174            ".el")
```